# What's the Nicest Way to do This? (Qt and Enum style arguments)

Tags: qt, dictionary, struct, enums, settings

In Qt, it is common to see something similar to the following:

```
QSettings obj3(QSettings::SystemScope, "MySoft", "Star Runner");
```

The important bit is the QSettings::SystemScope, which is an enum.

I want to have a settings provider (pay no attention to the previous example here, it has nothing to do with the following), with a get/set property.

```
Settings.set(Settings::refreshRate)
```

The refreshRate has to link to a key (string), and a default value (variant).

Should I make an enum and two dicts for the key and default values, or make a struct and a whole bunch of variables that encapsulate the settings I need? Should I try something else?

Thanks!

Edit!

This is what I did.

```cpp
// Interface
class Settings {
public:
  static QVariant get(Setting setting);
  static void set(Setting setting, QVariant value);

  const static Setting serverRefreshRate;
  const static Setting serverReportTimeout;
};

// Implementation
const Setting Settings::serverRefreshRate   = { "server/refreshRate",   10000 };
const Setting Settings::serverReportTimeout = { "server/reportTimeout", 1000 };
```

Comment: Please post an answer to your question as an answer. It doesn't belong in the question itself.

Comment: Instead of using a `Settings` class, you could also use a namespace with same name. In the interface, you can declare the `Setting` variables extern. You'd define them in the implementation just like you do now. A class with all-static members is not an idiom - that's what namespaces are for, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess since you're using `enum` which most likely will be easily castable to numbers from to `0` to `N-1` I guess just storing variants and strings in two vectors or one vector of pairs would work just fine.

There's also another question though -- how to initialize all of that and how you will be adding new settings to it. I can suggest two methods - first one writing a bunch of function calls with arguments: `enum`, `string`, `variant`. Thus way though if programmer adds another value to enum he can forget to call initializing function. The other way is to create function (or maybe two) which will do switch on all enum values (without default case) and will return pair of `string` and `variant`. You can turn on the compiler warning about all enum values being processed in switch and thus way control if you forget to implement some of them in that function. And then initialize your structures using loop on all of enum values. These initializing functions should be called somewhere near the beginning of your program (before reading settings initially).

Well, that's my thoughts on it, you are free to try some different ways though.

Comment: Actually, I've not yet got an implementation, so I don't yet have an enum. I want to know the 'prettiest' way to do this. Enum or loads of struct variables?

Comment: @user2195592 oh and I was speaking a lot only about enum sorry) Actually enum way is very nice while all of your settings fit to `QVariant`. With loads of structures you have to write `load/save` (and possibly `get` if you store them separately) manually which could be a bit tiresome and error-prone. You will still need to init them on form or read them from form of course though, but having enum could save you at least from some code duplication.